# Ultra high-pitched squeal noise coming from motherboard [?] when NOT moving mouse

Tags: mouse, noise

**EDIT:** It was actually the Logitech G500 mouse emitting a high-pitched whine or squeal, not the motherboard. More information here: http://jdc.parodius.com/logitech/. I suggest contacting Logitech support if you're affected.

---

I have an Asus Gene Z motherboard which I'm using with a Logitech G500 USB mouse.

I have noticed an **extremely** annoying quiet but high-pitched squeal coming from the motherboard. I thought it was the fans at first, then the hard drives, and even thought it was an SSD at one point but it turns out it seems to be coming from the motherboard itself, somewhere around the I/O or PCI-E slots.

The noise is constant when the mouse is idle, but **it stops when I start moving the mouse.** I thought this was highly unusual and it seems that most other similar problems I've read about occur when the mouse IS being moved. Not in this case, however.

I have tried using a PS/2 adapter with the mouse but I don't think the G500 supports this as it needs USB. I have also tried with another mouse (G5). I have tried all my USB ports. I have also tried reducing the mouse polling rate from 1000 to 125 but nothing works.

Any suggestions, please? I have already RMA'd this board once, and I really can't be bothered disassembling and returning it again.

Thanks.

Comment: It may have nothing to do with the mouse. The thing is: if you were to bring up resource monitor (etc) and look at cpu activity, when you wiggle the mouse, the cpu usage will go up (mouse, interrupts, and repaint). It is small, but it is there. Perhaps the CPU is idling down and you wind up with some strange convergence which induces vibration (voltage regulator, fan speed etc.).

Comment: You may be right, horatio. Any suggestions for a CPU-intensive test I could do to check it's the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually the Logitech G500 mouse emitting a high-pitched whine or squeal, not the motherboard. More information here: http://jdc.parodius.com/logitech/. I suggest contacting Logitech support if you're affected.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with EBGreen. In our disposable, throw it out and buy a new one age a computer shop would probably just tell you to buy a new motherboard.

If you, or a friend, can solder, then you could probably replace this part, which will cost a $1 or so, yourself. Do this *before* the capacitor actually fails as it could take other parts (like the CPU and memory) with it.

If you have a microphone (like a boom mike on your headset) you could try moving it around to see where the noise is loudest and attempt to isolate the suspect part.

Comment: Good idea; I didn't think of using a mic. I suspect my cheap mic might not be able to pick up the high frequency, though. I'd guess it's almost beyond my hearing level because it's so piercing and quite quiet.

If you're suggesting soldering as the solution then I'll just return the board. I'm scared this is just an issue with laser mice though because my (cheap, horrible) optical mouse doesn't exhibit the issue but both my laser mice do.

Comment: If it is still under warranty then absolutely return it. It may be a design defect with this particular motherboard and you might consider changing it out for a different one.

Comment: It was only bought days ago so yes I can return it. I think I'll do this and let you know what happens. I'd absolutely change it for a different model but unfortunately it's a high-end mATX board and there are very few options on the market. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The noise is all about the mouse PCB. the cause is due to the faulty manufacturing or incompatible resistors/capacitors used in it. otherwise they might get damaged like mentioned [here](http://forums.techarena.in/hardware-peripherals/1458310.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You my friend have a filtering capacitor that is about to pop. Not a whole lot that you can do about it really. You could feel the caps trying to find a hot one although they will all be pretty warm.

Comment: The strange thing is, I can hear the noise when I'm far away from the computer, but can't seem to isolate it with my ears right up close. My walls seem to be acting as amplifiers. All I know is it's extremely high pitched, just on the cusp of my hearing limit. I can still hear it over music and fans, however.

I didn't want to have to RMA this board as I did it once before last week (for a faulty LAN port). I suppose I will, though. Let this be a lesson to avoid Asus, perhaps. Thanks.

Comment: it's a very invasive noise in my experience. JohhnyBoats is right that you can try to isolate it with a mic, but yeah if it is new then I would RMA it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue (high pitched sound when NOT moving mouse) with motherboard GA-Z68MA-D2H-B3. And finally I have solved this sound nightmare! With my fingers I determined what element cause this high pitch sound (when I pressed it, sound disappear) and it was this choke - 
[image: choke]

I decided to insert some rubber stuff as spacer and it helped!

[image: workaround]

Now I can work at my PC with pleasure! :)